# Spring Integration FileReadingMessageSource use UseWatchService

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I use `FileReadingMessageSource` as source for Message in Spring Integration ESB.

In particular I would like to use the `WatchServiceDirectoryScanner`. I use the Annotation based configuration with spring boot.

If I do not use `WatchServiceDirectoryScanner` everything is fine but when I set `setUseWatchService(true)` I can't get it to work.

Only the file present in the directory when the application starts are generate new messages in the channel. The files copied or created in the directory do not generate any message.

I would like to use `WatchServiceDirectoryScanner` since I want to generate a message only

This is the code where I configure the channel the adapter and the source:

```
    @Bean(name="source")
    public FileReadingMessageSource getFileMessageSource(){
        FileReadingMessageSource lm = new FileReadingMessageSource();
        lm.setBeanName("fileMessageSource");
        lm.setDirectory(new File("C:/DestDir"));
        lm.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);

        lm.setFilter(new AcceptAllFileListFilter<>());
        lm.setUseWatchService(true);
        lm.setWatchEvents(WatchEventType.CREATE);
        return lm;
    }

@Bean(name="channel")
    public PublishSubscribeChannel getFileChannel(){
        PublishSubscribeChannel psc = new PublishSubscribeChannel();
        psc.setLoggingEnabled(true);
        psc.setComponentName("channelexp");
        return psc;

    }


    @Bean
    @DependsOn({"source","channel"})
    public SourcePollingChannelAdapter  getChannelAdapter(){
        SourcePollingChannelAdapter spca = new SourcePollingChannelAdapter();
        FileReadingMessageSource frms = context.getBean(FileReadingMessageSource.class);
        PublishSubscribeChannel psc = context.getBean("channel",PublishSubscribeChannel.class);
        spca.setSource(frms);
        spca.setOutputChannel(psc);
        return spca;
    }
```

Even If I use `@InboundChannelAdapter` there is no difference

```
@Bean(name="source")
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "channel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000"))
    public FileReadingMessageSource getFileMessageSource(){
        FileReadingMessageSource lm = new FileReadingMessageSource();
        lm.setDirectory(new File("C:/fromDir/"));
        lm.setFilter(new AcceptAllFileListFilter<>());
        lm.setUseWatchService(true);
        lm.setWatchEvents(WatchEventType.CREATE);
        return lm;
    }
```

Where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging to observe the watch events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see polling code in your configuration, but I wonder if you have anything else there:

1. You have to use `@EnableIntegration`
2. The `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` should be supplied with the `PollerMetadata`
3. Or just consider to use `@InboundChannelAdapter` (See [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.4.RELEASE/reference/html/files.html#_configuring_with_java_configuration_8))
4. It is really looks odd to use `context.getBean()` during bean definition. You should use *injection* there. The former is for runtime and not for initialization phase.

**EDIT**

Spring Integration Java DSL sample:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FileChangeLineSeparator {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(FileChangeLineSeparator.class)
                .web(false)
                .run(args);
        System.out.println("Put a windows file with a .txt extension in /tmp/in,"
                + "\nthe file will be converted to Un*x and placed in"
                + "\n/tmp/out"
                + "\n\nHit enter to terminate");
        System.in.read();
        context.close();
    }

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "channel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000"))
public FileReadingMessageSource getFileMessageSource() {
    FileReadingMessageSource lm = new FileReadingMessageSource();
    lm.setDirectory(new File("/tmp/in"));
    lm.setFilter(new AcceptAllFileListFilter<>());
    lm.setUseWatchService(true);
    lm.setWatchEvents(FileReadingMessageSource.WatchEventType.CREATE);
    return lm;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fileToFile() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("channel")                 
                .transform(Transformers.fileToString())
                .transform("payload.replaceAll('\r\n', '\n')")
                .handle(Files.outboundAdapter("'/tmp/out'")
                        .autoCreateDirectory(true))
                .get();
    }

}
```

I have created new files eventually and they are picked up properly and processed.

Comment: Yes I releaze it is odd but I'm planning to use this code at runtime .

Comment: Well, for runtime there are a lot to do... Consider to study Spring Integration Java DSL `IntegrationFlowContext` feature: https://spring.io/blog/2016/10/14/java-dsl-for-spring-integration-1-2-release-is-available. Just read all the related blogs post about new features. Also take a look into sample https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-tcp-client

Answer (score 1):

Even if  @Artem Bilan answer was very useful (that's why I accepted it) I post my own answer to show my final solution.

This is the [complete example](https://github.com/Panciz/springint-dirmonitor)

I had to monitor a directory and create a message every time a file is modified.
I use Spring ESB `FileReadingMessageSource`.
Moreover I had to instantiate all the components at runtime, for this reason I used  Spring Integration Java DSL `IntegrationFlowContext`.

This is how I intitiated the Source at run time (the message are sent to an `"output"` channel).

```
    @Autowired
    private IntegrationFlowContext intContext;

public void initDispatcher(String name,Long pollingFreq) throws HandlerConfigurationException {
        logger.info("Source "+ name +" Inizializing");


        IntegrationFlow sourceModifiedFlow = IntegrationFlows
                .from(this.getFileModifiedMessageSource(), s -> s.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(pollingFreq, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)))
                .channel("outputChannel").get();
        intContext.registration(sourceModifiedFlow).id(name)).autoStartup(true).register();
    }
```

This is how I create the actual `FileReader`.

```
 public FileReadingMessageSource getFileModifiedMessageSource() {
            FileReadingMessageSource lm = new FileReadingMessageSource();
            lm.setBeanName(String.format(SOURCE_MODIFIED_SUFFIX, name));
            lm.setDirectory(new File(readingDir));
            ModifiedOnlyFileScanner modifiedOnlyFileScanner = new ModifiedOnlyFileScanner(new File(readingDir));
            modifiedOnlyFileScanner.setFilter(new AcceptAllFileListFilter<>());
            lm.setScanner(modifiedOnlyFileScanner);

            return lm;
        }
```

The default file scanner (`org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.WatchServiceDirectoryScanner`) was not good for me. Mainly for two reason:

1. at startup generate a message for each file present in the directory
2. even if I configured the reader with `fileReadSource.setWatchEvents(WatchEventType.MODIFY);` , the source dispatch a message also when a new file is created into to the directory.

So I end up writing my own scanner. This is the complete code:

```
public class ModifiedOnlyFileScanner extends DefaultDirectoryScanner implements Lifecycle {
    private final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(FileDispatcher.class);


    private final ConcurrentMap<Path, WatchKey> pathKeys = new ConcurrentHashMap<Path, WatchKey>();

    private WatchService watcher;

    private WatchEvent.Kind<?>[] kinds;

    private File directory;

    @Override
    public void start() {
        try {
            this.watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Failed to create watcher for " + directory, e);
        }

        this.kinds = new WatchEvent.Kind<?>[]{StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY};
        walkDirectory(directory.toPath(), null);

    }

    public ModifiedOnlyFileScanner(File directory) {
        super();
        this.directory = directory;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        try {
            this.watcher.close();
            this.watcher = null;
            this.pathKeys.clear();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Failed to close watcher for " + directory, e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected File[] listEligibleFiles(File directory) {
        Assert.state(this.watcher != null, "The WatchService has'nt been started");
        Collection<File> files = filesFromEvents();
        if(files.size()>0){
            logger.info("Detected Modified files "+files);
        }
        return files.toArray(new File[files.size()]);
    }

    private Set<File> filesFromEvents() {
        WatchKey key = this.watcher.poll();
        Set<File> files = new LinkedHashSet<File>();
        while (key != null) {
            File parentDir = ((Path) key.watchable()).toAbsolutePath().toFile();
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY ) {
                    Path item = (Path) event.context();
                    File file = new File(parentDir, item.toFile().getName());
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        //I do not dig into directories
                        if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                            files.remove(file);
                            files.add(file);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                            logger.warn("A file [" + file + "] for the event [" + event.kind() +
                                    "] doesn't exist. Ignored.");
                    }
                }
            }
            key.reset();
            key = this.watcher.poll();
        }
        return files;
    }

    private Set<File> walkDirectory(Path directory, final WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind) {
        final Set<File> walkedFiles = new LinkedHashSet<File>();
        try {
            registerWatch(directory);
            Files.walkFileTree(directory, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

                @Override
                public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                    FileVisitResult fileVisitResult = super.preVisitDirectory(dir, attrs);
                    registerWatch(dir);
                    return fileVisitResult;
                }

                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                    FileVisitResult fileVisitResult = super.visitFile(file, attrs);
                    if (!StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY.equals(kind)) {
                        walkedFiles.add(file.toFile());
                    }
                    return fileVisitResult;
                }

            });
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Failed to walk directory: " + directory.toString(), e);
        }
        return walkedFiles;
    }

    private void registerWatch(Path dir) throws IOException {
        if (!this.pathKeys.containsKey(dir)) {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("registering: " + dir + " for file events");
            }
            WatchKey watchKey = dir.register(this.watcher, this.kinds);
            this.pathKeys.putIfAbsent(dir, watchKey);
        }
    }
}
```